# Why is routeNotificationForNexmo having no effect?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have SMS notifications that get sent via Nexmo. They are working, but I've changed how I set the recipient's phone number and need to override the default by using the routeNotificationForNexmo method.

However, it seems no matter what I do with that method, the app ignores it and nothing changes. I can change other things in this file, such as the SMS message contents, and see the changes in new messages sent from Nexmo.

Why isn't routeNotificationForNexmo working? Is there something else that could be overriding this?

Here is my whole /Notifications/TeamMessage.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;

class TeamMessage extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $custom_message;
    protected $short_code;
    protected $reply_to;
    protected $reply_to_name;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($custom_message, $short_code, $channels, $reply_to, $reply_to_name)
    {
        $this->custom_message = $custom_message;
        $this->short_code = $short_code;
        $this->channels = $channels;
        $this->reply_to = $reply_to;
        $this->reply_to_name = $reply_to_name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->channels; //
    }

    /**
     * Route notifications for the Nexmo channel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForNexmo()
    {
      $number = $this->phone_number_country . $this->phone_number;
      $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $number);  //Strips all non-numbers
      return $number;
    }

    /*  Send SMS   */
    public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
        return (new NexmoMessage)
            ->from(00000000000)
            ->content($this->custom_message . " \n\n Unsubscribe at http://" . env('TL_DOMAIN') . '/s/' . $this->short_code );
    }
    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->replyTo($this->reply_to, $this->reply_to_name)
            ->line($this->custom_message)
            ->line('--')
            ->line("To unsubscribe, go to http://" . env('TL_DOMAIN') . '/s/' . $this->short_code);
            //->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm on Laravel 5.3, running locally via Docker (Laradock). I've tried stopping and restarting all the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Not sure where I got the idea to put the routeNotificationForNexmo() function inside the notification class. It belongs in the the User class, User.php file.